# Attainable bounds for correlations for Gamma random variables?

Tags: correlation, gamma-distribution

I'd need to know if it's possible to reach [-1,1] bounds with Pearson's correlation with a generic pair of Gamma random variables. The problem as you may imagine is there's no known closed form for the quantile function (at least to my knowledge).
Is there a solution? Even a research paper could be enough, actually I haven't been finding anything.

Comment: Are both variables drawn from the same Gamma distributions, or are you asking about (say) a Gamma and a Gaussian?

Comment: How would the quantile function be related to bounds on correlation coefficients?

Comment: I was trying to replicate this reasoning...
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66775/attainable-correlations-for-exponential-random-variables/66776#66776

ps a generic pair of Gamma variables

Comment: An exponential variate is a $\Gamma(1)$ variable, so the answer you reference applies to any two Gamma variables with the *same* shape parameters both equal to $1$. It generalizes easily to other common shape parameter values. Although formulae may be difficult to obtain, two things can immediately be deduced from basic properties of Gamma variables (there is a one-to-one relationship between shape and skewness) and of correlation: the lower bound of $-1$ cannot be attained for different variables and the upper bound can be attained only when they have the same shape parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are *perfectly* correlated random variables (the Pearson
correlation coefficient $\rho$ has value $+1$ or $-1$), then it must be that $Y = \rho aX + b = \pm aX+b$ where $a >0$.

A Gamma random variable $X$ with shape parameter $t>0$ and scale parameter $\theta>0$ has density function
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\theta \cdot \Gamma(t)}\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{t-1}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon x>0\}}, ~~t > 0, ~~\theta > 0. \tag{1}$$
We write $X \sim \Gamma(t,\theta)$.

With this characterization, if $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly *positively*
correlated random variables and $X \sim \Gamma(t,\theta)$, then
$Y = aX+b \sim \Gamma(t, a\theta)$ provided that $b = 0$.
If $b \neq 0$, then $Y$ is a *displaced* Gamma random variable whose
density function is moved rightwards by $b$ units. Note that $X$ and $Y$
have the same shape parameter. It is not possible
for two Gamma random variables with different *shape* parameters to be
perfectly positively correlated.
On the other hand, **no** two Gamma random variables can have Pearson correlation coefficient $-1$. If $X \sim \Gamma(t,\theta)$, then $Y = -aX+b$  takes on negative values with positive probability, and thus cannot have a Gamma distribution.

A somewhat more general definition of Gamma random variables allows
$\theta$ to take on negative values, and the random variable takes
on positive values only or negative values only according as
$\theta > 0$ or $\theta < 0$. Thus, for $t > 0$ and
$\theta \neq 0$, we have that
$X \sim \Gamma(t,\theta)$ has density function 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{|\theta| \cdot \Gamma(t)}\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{t-1}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon 
\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(\theta)\}}\tag{2}$$
so that $-X \sim \Gamma(t,-\theta)$. With this characterization,
two perfectly correlated Gamma random variables $X$ and $Y$
necessarily have the same shape parameter while their scale
parameters must have the same sign or opposite sign according
as $\rho = +1$ or $\rho = -1$, and it must be that $Y = \rho a X$
where $a > 0$.

---

A [different generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) of Gamma random variables
is not considered here.

Comment: The problem becomes subtler and more interesting when you use a slightly more general notion of Gamma variable that includes negative scale parameters. That would rule out your argument, requiring a (slightly) more penetrating analysis of the situation. A more challenging way to understand the question would be to obtain upper and lower bounds for the correlations as a function of the two shape and two scale parameters.

Comment: @whuber Could you provide a reference for the slightly more general notion of Gamma random variables? [Wikipedia's version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) has positive-valued random variables. If negative scale parameters mean a reflected Gamma distribution (RV takes on negative values only), then $X \sim \Gamma(t,\lambda)$ makes $-aX$ a $\Gamma(t, -\lambda/a)$ random variable perfectly negatively correlated with $X$.

Comment: To understand this generalization, which you have done correctly, requires no reference, so references are of interest only insofar as they indicate that the generalization has potential use. To that end, *inter alia*, Bieniek and Szynal, *Limit Distribution of Differences and Quotients of Non-adjacent kth Record Values* (Probability and Mathematical Statistics, vol. 23, Fasc. 1, 2003) employ this generalization.  (They use a different terminology, though: to make all scale parameters positive they consider Gammas with negative scales to be "Negative Gamma" distributions.)

Comment: just what I was asking for! thanks (also for the intuition behind the result!)